# Integration of $\sin^2x$ without using double angle identity of $\cos 2x$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

I want to integrate $\sin^2x$ without using the double angle identity of $\cos2x$.

Here's what I tried:
$$
\int \sin^2x dx
= \int \sin x \tan x \cos x dx
$$
Let $u = \sin x$ => $du = \cos x dx$

And if $u = \sin x$, $\tan x = \frac{u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}$, therefore

$$
=\int u × \frac{u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}du = \int \frac{u^2}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}du
$$
Now if $t = \sqrt{1 - u^2}$, $2dt = \frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}$ and $u^2 = 1 - t^2$
$$
= 2\int (1-t^2)dt = 2t - \frac{2t^3}{3}$$
Substituting back $u$ and $\sin x$

$$
= 2\sqrt{1-u^2} - \frac{2}{3}(\sqrt{1 - u^2})^3
$$
$$
= 2\cos x - \frac{2}{3}\cos^3x
$$
But when you differentiate it you get $-2sin^3x$

All the steps seem right to me, why is the answer wrong or what I did is wrong, and is using the double angle formula the only way to integrate it?

Comment: $ \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}u} = \frac{-2u}{2\sqrt{1-u^2}},$ not $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-u^2}}.$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find both $$\int \sin^2xdx$$ and $$\int \cos^2 x dx $$ at the same time using the following.

Apply integration by parts on $$\int \sin^2xdx$$ using $u=\sin x $ and $dv=\sin x dx $ to get $$\int \sin^2 xdx= -\sin x \cos x + \int \cos^2 xdx$$

Thus we have a system $$ \int \sin^2xdx-\int \cos^2 xdx= -\sin x \cos x$$
$$ \int \sin^2xdx+\int \cos^2 x dx = \int 1 dx =x$$
Upon adding and subtracting the two above formulas you will get the answer for both$$ \int \sin^2 xdx=(1/2)(x-\sin x \cos x)+C$$ and  $$\int \cos^2x dx=(1/2)(x+\sin x \cos x)+C$$

Comment: Wow, this is a really beautiful way of doing it sir, thank you for letting me know this.

Comment: Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid using the double angle formula by integrating by parts $$\int\sin^2x\,\mathrm{d}x = -\cos x \sin x + \int \cos^2 x \,\mathrm{d}x = -\cos x \sin x + x - \int \sin^2 x \,\mathrm{d}x. $$

Comment: It wasn't clear to me why the last step occured, but I think I like this way of using the most basic trig identity to find the original integral.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to apply the chain rule:  $$t=\sqrt{1-u^2}\implies dt=-\frac{u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,du.$$

Comment: Yeah thanks I forgot to apply the chain rule, thatmade the answer lengthy but I got the right answer after the correction

Answer (score 2):

If $t=\sqrt{1-u^2}$, then$$\mathrm dt=-\frac u{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,\mathrm du\quad\text{and}\quad u^2=1-t^2.$$So,\begin{align}\int\frac{u^2}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,\mathrm du&=-\int u\frac{-u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,\mathrm du\\&=-\int\sqrt{1-t^2}\,\mathrm dt\\&=-\frac12\left(t\sqrt{1-t^2}+\arcsin (t)\right).\end{align}

Comment: Doesn't the question become how you show the last identity without using the double angle formulae? I don't find this very obvious.

Comment: @stochasticboy321: You can use the substitution $t=\sin\theta$ to convert $\int \sqrt{1-t^2} \, dt$ to $\int \cos^2\theta \, d\theta$. Then, we can use your method. But this does mean that this method is quite lengthy, unless the value of $\int \sqrt{1-t^2} \, dt$ is already known.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 the last identity can be proved using integration by parts

Comment: Yes thank you I forgot to apply the chain rule. This made the answer really lengthy but I got the right answer now.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 I show the last identity without using the double angle formulae as follows:\begin{align}\int\sqrt{1-t^2}\,\mathrm dt&=\int\frac{1-t^2}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,\mathrm dt\\&=\int\frac1{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,\mathrm dt-\int\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,\mathrm dt\\&=\arcsin(t)+\int t\frac{-t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\,\mathrm dt\\&=\arcsin(t)+t\sqrt{1-t^2}-\int\sqrt{1-t^2}\,\mathrm dt\end{align}

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I love this place, I got here to learn about $\sin^2x$ but I'm learning more integration techniques. I like your way of provingit because trigonometry sometimes confuses me, using algebra to do it it quite nice

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 1):

People have already mentioned that $\frac{dt}{du}$ = -$\frac{u}{t}$ but if you follow that line your integral then becomes:

$\int \frac{1-t^2}{t^2} \sqrt{1-t^2} dt$

Which may not be any prettier to solve. As an alternative I suggest using Euler's identity to solve this.

$sin(x) = \frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$

It'll be much quicker to get to the answer with much more trivial integrals to solve.

Comment: Using $e^{ix}$ may be beyond the scope of the original poster's education.  However, nice approach, all the same.

Comment: Yes the above user is right. I still got a lot of maths to learn and I'm not aware of writing sinx using Euler's identity. But I tried integrating it with your method and the process was beautiful, thank you. I am eager to learn more about this in the future.